# flutter intl localisation in multi-screen app problem

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating a multi-screen application and I am using intl localization to localize the application. what if I have each screen in a separate file with Scaffold( for ex. home.dart, and more). And to use intl commands you need to register the command in MaterialApp(), which I only have in main.dart.

I tried use this command in main.dart, and these intl localisation commands didn't work on others screens

Answer (score 0):

Even if your application will have multiple screens, and each of them are in different files, your application will have a single entrypoint, the MaterialApp.

So when you declare the internationalisation in the MaterialApp, and you include the different screens inside the MaterialApp (with a router, or a state...) the internationalisation will be available for all the screens.

Comment: I did it all, but it doesnt work for me